# I Need a recommendation for a CMS application with ECommerce

Tags: recommendations, cms, ecommerce

Does anyone have any recommendation for an open source solution for a robust CMS application that has a fully featured ECommerce module?  I have been looking into Drupal with Ubercart -- but it looks like Ubercart is not fully up to speed with Drupal 7, and the other modules for Ecommerce don't look as robust. The CMS system should support [CMIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/cmis-spec-v1.0.html) as both client and server, and be able to run in a cloud computing environment.

The system could be written in any standard web programming language, although Java would be my preference.  I'm posting this question here because it seems that all CMS systems provide ECommerce as an afterthought, rather than a core feature.

Comment: This site is for **consumers** of web applications not **producers** of web applications. For the latter type of question [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) is a the place to ask. However, don't repost - the question can be migrated.

Comment: Gotcha. I did look at the FAQ, but must have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favourite is Magento. It's PHP, and there is a free version available. The difference between the paid for version and free version is that no support is offered with the free version. This doesn't mean you can't get help on it, because the community is very big and very helpful!

In my opinion, ZenCart is far too complicated to be of any use to anyone, same with CubeCart. ExpressionEngine is alright, but I doubt it is any good for eCommerce, although as a Blog platform it's my preferred choice (even over Wordpress).

As for Drupal, make like the English in the middle ages and avoid it like the plague!

Comment: I don't understand why Drupal is so popular, I find it quite restrictive and difficult.

Comment: Well, there are some other differences between the commercial and community editions of Magento (support for customer credits, gift cards, store credit, etc.), but they're superfluous for most stores. However, I'm curious what you have against Drupal? I wouldn't build an e-commerce system on it (or most CMSes), but as a CMS framework it seems pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

[Zencart](http://www.zen-cart.com/)?

Comment: Zen is **only** a cart.

Comment: You can add extra pages, so I would say it's more than a cart.

Comment: Being able to add some pages(intended for say, shipping/returns info, etc.) is not nearly the same thing as saying it's a CMS. The poster started out looking at Drupal. Are you honestly drawing a similarity here?

Answer (score 0):

ExpressionEngine ships with a module called Simple Commerce that'd probably cover most basic needs. It also has a few third-party ones like CartThrob if you need more.

As for Drupal, you might actually look at basing your project on v6(which isn't going anywhere for a while). Depending upon your possibly needing other modules, v7 as a whole might've been out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A non-turnkey solution is a basic CMS mixed with FoxyCart. If your needs are modest, and you are offering basic options, FoxyCart is simply awesome and can integrate into any site with just a little HTML/CSS setup.

http://www.foxycart.com

I use it with TextPattern.